# Initialize coffeescript (backbone) class from HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

This might turn out to be a stupid typo but just incase there is a Gotcha about this. I am just starting with CoffeeScript inside rails application.

I created a class PeopleView in people.js.coffee:

```
class PeopleView extends Backbone.View
....
```

I am trying to initialize it from HTML file:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var view = new PeopleView();
   });
</script>
```

I am getting an error that PeopleView is not defined. I can see in the compiled application.js that PeopleView is defined. Is there something that needs to be done to initialize classes outside of the coffeescript file?

-- Edit

I just noticed that typing

```
window.PeopleView = PeopleView
```

at the bottom of the people.js.coffee file will make it work. Is this a good method?

Comment: yes, and it also helps in testing your code in browser's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.PeopleView = PeopleView
```

Yes, this is the correct method. CoffeeScript code will be compiled into an anonymous function call, so all declarations will be constrained to that function's scope, unless you make them visible in outer scope by assigning to a window property.

This helps preventing accidental overwrite of global variables.